# Hanami: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, hanami

I keep learning hanami and ran into the following problem: when I initialize and check the parameters, I encounter the following error

```
Boot Error
Something went wrong while loading /Users/anewaccount/Projects/Mediateka/config.ru

NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/dry-validation-0.11.0/lib/dry/validation/schema/deprecated.rb:11:in `input_processor'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/dry-validation-0.11.0/lib/dry/validation/schema/class_interface.rb:165:in `default_options'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/dry-validation-0.11.0/lib/dry/validation/schema/class_interface.rb:35:in `new'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-validations-1.3.7/lib/hanami/validations.rb:109:in `validations'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-controller-1.3.3/lib/hanami/action/params.rb:152:in `params'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-controller-1.3.3/lib/hanami/action/validatable.rb:100:in `block in params'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-controller-1.3.3/lib/hanami/action/validatable.rb:100:in `class_eval'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-controller-1.3.3/lib/hanami/action/validatable.rb:100:in `params'
/Users/anewaccount/Projects/Mediateka/apps/web/controllers/auth/sign_up.rb:11:in `<class:SignUp>'
/Users/anewaccount/Projects/Mediateka/apps/web/controllers/auth/sign_up.rb:9:in `<module:Auth>'
/Users/anewaccount/Projects/Mediateka/apps/web/controllers/auth/sign_up.rb:8:in `<module:Controllers>'
/Users/anewaccount/Projects/Mediateka/apps/web/controllers/auth/sign_up.rb:7:in `<module:Web>'
/Users/anewaccount/Projects/Mediateka/apps/web/controllers/auth/sign_up.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-utils-1.3.8/lib/hanami/utils.rb:56:in `require_relative'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-utils-1.3.8/lib/hanami/utils.rb:56:in `block in require!'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-utils-1.3.8/lib/hanami/utils.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-utils-1.3.8/lib/hanami/utils.rb:94:in `for_each_file_in'
/Users/anewaccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/hanami-utils-1.3.8/lib/hanami/utils.rb:56:in `require!'
```

my action:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'pry-byebug'
require_relative 'auth_base_action'

module Web
  module Controllers
    module Auth
      class SignUp < AuthBaseAction

        params do
          required(:user).schema do
            required(:first_name).filled(:str?)
            required(:last_name).filled(:str?)
            required(:email).filled(:str?, format?: /@/)
            required(:password).filled(:str?).confirmation
          end
        end

        def call params
          binding.pry
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I wrote the params block according to the example from the official documentation on the idea that it should work, but I catch NoMethodError: undefined method `size 'for nil: NilClass I also saw in the official documentation that these validations are delegated from Hanami :: Validations, I installed gem' hanami- validation 'according to their official documentation, but I had the same error, then I started looking at other people's code and they were successful using the example from the official documentation. Please tell me what is the error or please explain what am I doing wrong? I'm already very confused

Comment: StackOverflow isn't meant for bug reporting. Please use GitHub issues for that: https://github.com/hanami/hanami/issues/new

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report.